# Customizing results from datagridview

Tags: vb.net

When my CustomersBindingSource searches for a customer from a datagridview, 
I need a message box showing "No Result Found" when it finds no match rather than just
displaying nothing.

Comment: So do it then.  When you've tried, if it doesn't work as you expect, show us what you did and we can help you work out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Dim emptyRowCount As Integer = IIf(DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows, 1, 0)
Dim filterRowCount As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
If filterRowCount <= emptyRowCount Then MessageBox.Show("No Result Found")
```

i put the first line because if it finds no match and you have `DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = True`, it get 1 the empty new row is counting, and it get 0 if you have `DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False`.